# How to Converted Image into text for use in tkinter code

Tags: python, tkinter

How to Converted Image into  This type of text for use in tkinter code.

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    root=Tk()
    
    photo = """
    R0lGODlhDQAQAPQAAFw1Zl42Z2A6amE6amI7a2I8a2I8bKeHqK6BqbSLsLWLsLuV
    t7ufu7yfu72hvL6ivb6ivr+jvsKgvsWlwseow8iqxcmrxs+1zNC2zdO70dS90tW9
    0tW+0wAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAB0ALAAAAAANABAAAAVMYCd2QFmOKJltGZCOwMZt
    7kvKtH3P9RvzutgmZ4tdiL6NBUkyGTaSjMHkEjgyGcuiwnIIRoWIJUG2eFPhCYJy
    fhUkmLbNcPjqRL1RCAA7
    """

    root.mainloop()
```

Please Help!
Thank U in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an image that has been base64-encoded.

For example, given a file named "image.gif", you can encode it like so:

```
with open("image.gif", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    imagedata = base64.b64encode(data)
```

`imagedata` will have a string in the same format as your example.